# Runtime error Codeforces (71A) - Python

Tags: python

firstly, I would like to state that the question I am about to ask is not related to any homework or competiton.

Now, I recently started out with codeforces. I am using Python 2.7.10 to code. The link to the question is this - http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/71/A

```
n = input('Enter the test cases :')
b=[]

while n>0:
    a = raw_input('Enter the string :')
    b.append(a)
    n=n-1
t = 0
while t<len(b):
    if len(b[t]) > 10:
        length = len(b[t])-2
        length = str(length)
        c = b[t]
        print c[0] + length + c[len(c)-1]
    else:
        print b[t]
    t=t+1
```

The problem I am experiencing is that it says runtime error on test case 1.

My answer comes out fine as mentioned is their test cases. I suppose my syntax is wrong!

I hope you guys can help me out. 
Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Syntax errors produce `SyntaxError`s, not runtime errors.

Comment: Can you tell me what the problem is?

Comment: I think there is a problem _inside_ CodeForces as your code seems OK to me.

Answer (score 4):

When taking input you are printing some extra lines like 'Enter the test cases :'. In codeforces your output has to exactly match with the desired output. Printing anything extra will give a verdict of wrong answer or run time error.